# std::abs for "unsigned long long int" data type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Why should I get this error

```
 C2668: 'abs' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

For a simple code like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
int main()
{
  unsigned long long int a = 10000000000000;
  unsigned long long int b = 20000000000000;
  std::cout << std::abs(a-b) << "\n";   // ERROR
  return 0;
}
```

The error still presents after removing `std::`. However if I use `int` data type (with smaller values) there is no problem.

The traditional solution is to check that manually

```
std::cout << (a<b) ? (b-a) : (a-b) << "\n";
```

Is that the only solution?

Comment: Why do you want to `abs` an unsigned type?? (not a rhetorical question)

Comment: @Mario they want to abs the *difference* between two unsigned values.

Comment: Aren't unsigned types wrapping around? The result of `a-b` is not `-10000000000000` but `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()-10000000000000` (still unsigned long long).

Comment: @mahmood Note that `<<` has higher precedence than `?:`, so remember your brackets! http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The check seem the only really good solution. Alternatives require type bigger than yours and nonstandard extension to use it.

You can go with solutions casting to signed long long if your range fits. I would hardly suggest that way, especially if the implementation is placed in a function that does only that.

Answer (score 5):

You are including `<cmath>` and thus using the "[floating-point `abs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs)".

The "[integer `abs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs)" is declared in `<cstdlib>`.

However, there is no overload for `unsigned long long int` (both `a` and `b` are, thus `a-b` is, too), and the overload for `long long int` only exists since C++11.

Comment: C++11 does provide for a integral overload in `cmath`, [see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/CuyXeQC14pZwVzYg) although [it will probably not do what you want it to](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29750946/1708801) ... `gcc` is the only one to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to include the correct header. As pointed out by gx_, `<cmath>` has a floating-point abs and on my compiler it actually compiles, but the result is probably not the one you expected:

```
1.84467e+19
```

Include `<cstdlib>` instead. Now the error is:

```
main.cpp:7:30: error: call of overloaded ‘abs(long long unsigned int)’ is ambiguous
main.cpp:7:30: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:771:12: note: int abs(int)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/cstdlib:139:3: note: long int std::abs(long int)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/cstdlib:173:3: note: long long int __gnu_cxx::abs(long long int)
```

As you can see, there is no `unsigned` overload of this function, because computing an absolute value of something which is of type `unsigned` makes no sense.

I see answers suggesting you to cast an `unsigned` type to a signed one, but I believe this is *dagereous*, unless you really know what you are doing!
Let me ask first what is the expected range of the values `a` and `b` that you are going to operate on? If both are below `2^63-1` I would strongly suggest to just use `long long int`. If that is not true however, let me note that your program for the values:

```
a=0, b=1
```

and

```
a=2^64-1, b=0
```

will produce *exactly the same result*, because you actually need 65 bits to represent any possible outcome of a difference of 2 64-bit values. If you can confirm that this is not going to be a problem, use the cast as suggested. However, if you don't know, you may need to rethink what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score -2):

Because back before C++ with C you used to have use abs, fabs, labs for each different type, c++ allows overloading of abs, in this case it doesn't understand or isn't happy with your overload.

Use `labs(a-b)` seeing as you're using longs, this should solve your problem.

Comment: @mahmood Yes, a-b will overflow(underflow) if a < b. abs() cannot help you check that for unsigned long long types. The result of a-b in this case is an unsigned type. unsigned types cannot be negative.

Comment: yeah what @nos said, sorry I thought this was common sense?

Comment: `long` is not the same as `long long`.