# Is std::abs(0u) ill-formed?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, cmath

Given the following program:

```
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    std::abs(0u) ;
}
```

`gcc` and `clang` disagree on whether this is ill-formed. Using `gcc` with `libstdc++` the code builds without error or warning (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5sASqwTFEidudt0S)*), while using `clang` with `libc++` it generates the following error (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xRL9kXz2sjeda2ZE)*):

```
error: call to 'abs' is ambiguous
std::abs(0u) ;
^~~~~~~~
```

Which result is correct? Should `abs(0u)` be ambiguous or not?

---

MSalters points out an interesting related question: [Template version of std::abs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29411486/1708801).

Answer (score 17):

Looks like `libstdc++` is correct, this is not ill-formed, although we will see there are some doubts expressed over whether this is a defect in LWG active issue `2192`.

The draft C++11 standard section `26.8` *[c.math]* paragraph `11` says:

> Moreover, there shall be additional overloads sufficient to ensure:

and includes the following item:

> 2. Otherwise, if any argument corresponding to a double parameter has type double or an integer type, then all arguments corresponding to
>      double parameters are effectively cast to double.

and we can see this `libstdc++` does [indeed provide for this](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/c_std/cmath#L92) case:

```
template<typename _Tp>
inline typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<__is_integer<_Tp>::__value,
                                                  double>::__type
abs(_Tp __x)
{ return __builtin_fabs(__x); }
```

There is a also a `gcc` bug report [std::abs (long long) resorts to std::abs (double) if llabs is absent](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54686), which questions if this implementation is correct and one response says:

> [...]is fine per the Standard, any integer is supposed to
>   unconditionally become double. [...]

The bug report eventually lead to [LWG active issue 2192: Validity and return type of std::abs(0u) is unclear](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2192) being filed which says amongst other things:

> 1. In C++11 the additional "sufficient overload" rule from 26.8 [c.math]
>      p11 (see also LWG 2086) can be read to be applicable to the std::abs()
>      overloads as well, which can lead to the following possible
>      conclusions:
>
> The program
>
> ```
>     #include <type_traits>
>     #include <cmath>
>
>     static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(std::abs(0u)), double>(), "Oops");
>
>     int main() {
>       std::abs(0u); // Calls std::abs(double)
>     }
> ```
>
> is required to be well-formed, because of sub-bullet 2 ("[..] or an
>   integer type [..]") of 26.8 [c.math] p11 (Note that the current
>   resolution of LWG 2086 doesn't fix this problem).
>
> 2. Any translation unit including both  and  might be ill-formed because of two conflicting requirements for the return type
>      of the overload std::abs(int).
>
> It seems to me that at least the second outcome is not intended,
>   personally I think that both are unfortunate [...] It should also be
>   noted, that the corresponding "generic type function" rule set from
>   C99/C1x in 7.25 p2+3 is restricted to the floating-point functions
>   from  and , so cannot be applied to the abs
>   functions (but to the fabs functions!).

The question is whether this was intended to apply to `abs` as well. This could be a defect since there does not seem to a way to interpret the current wording to exclude `abs`.

So current wording indicates `libstdc++` is conformant, it is not clear why `libc++` has chosen their current implementation as it is. I can find no bug reports nor discussions involving this topic and the LWG issue does not mention diverging implementations.

The proposed solution would make `std::abs(0u)` ill-formed:

> If abs() is called with an argument of unsigned integral type that
>   cannot be converted to int by integral promotion ([conv.prom]), the
>   program is ill-formed. [Note: arguments that can be promoted to int
>   are permitted for compatibility with C. — end note]

While some may question the notion of using `abs` with an unsigned type Howard Hinnant points out in the report that when using templates such consequences may not be apparent and provides an example:

> [...]especially in C++ where we have templates, and the types involved
>   are not always apparent to the programmer at design time. For example,
>   consider:
>
> ```
> template <class Int>
> Int
> analyze(Int x, Int y)
> {
>   // ...
>   if (std::abs(x - y) < threshold)
>   {
>     // ...
>   }
>   // ...
> }
> ```

Comment: [2192 was moved to a defect](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2192)