# Ambiguous call to abs

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, cmath

I have a custom data type that in practice can be either `float` or `double`. On every OS except OSX, I am able to successfully build this C++11 template:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>

template< class REAL_T >
inline REAL_T inhouse_abs(REAL_T i_val)
{
    return std::abs((REAL_T)i_val);
}

int main()
{
    int32_t ui = 2;
    inhouse_abs(ui);
    return 0;
}
```

However, clang 6.0 (3.5 LLVM) reports an ambiguous function call. If I change `abs` to `fabs`, the error is resolved on OSX, but now an identical error shows up on my Linux clang, gcc, and Visual Studio.

Error on Visual Studio with fabs:

```
349 error C2668: 'fabs' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

**UPDATE**

This example compiled on our OS X systems, although in the *nearly* identical project it does not. The solution was including `<cstdlib>` explicitly in the source, rather than back in another header. The reason is unclear, but seems to be xcode/clang not following our header includes properly.

Comment: Do you have the actual error text?

Comment: @Collin Added the Visual Studio error. Will need a minute to find the clang  analog.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour The error is generated at that line without any calls necessary.

Comment: So what headers are you including etc....

Comment: Updated with example.

Comment: Your fully example make more sense now. Updated my original answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is that `libc++` is not entirely C++11 compliant with the integral overload for [std::abs in cmath](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs):

```
double      fabs( Integral arg ); (7)   (since C++11)
```

Including [cstdlib](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) solves your problem since that header has overloads specifically for integer types.

For reference the draft C++11 standard section `26.8` *[c.math]* paragraph `11` says:

> Moreover, there shall be additional overloads sufficient to ensure:

and includes the following item:

> 2. Otherwise, if any argument corresponding to a double parameter has type double or an integer type, then all arguments corresponding to
>      double parameters are effectively cast to double.

This is situation very likely to change due to [LWG active issue 2192: Validity and return type of std::abs(0u) is unclear](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2192). I am guessing `libc++` choose not to provide the overloads in `cmath` due to the issue brought up in this defect report.

See [Is std::abs(0u) ill-formed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29750946/1708801) for more details on this.

Answer (score 4):

The solution was to explicitly `#include <cstdlib>` on the OS X machine, as for some reason Visual Studio finds it in our dependencies and includes it, but clang does not. I will try to reproduce a similar chain of includes that our project has and reproduce the error in a minimalist way, as it may still be a problem either with Xcode or Visual Studio.

Comment: Helped me in my project written in Xcode, too. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I saved somebody else some time!

Answer (score 1):

If you have many template functions causing this problem, you can use the following drop-in replacement:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <type_traits>

namespace util {


template <class T>
auto abs(T value) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<T>::value,
                                      T> { return value; }
template <class T>
auto abs(T value) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value,
                                      T> { return std::fabs(value); }
template <class T>
auto abs(T value) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, int>::value,
                                      T> { return std::abs(value); }
template <class T>
auto abs(T value) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, long>::value,
                                      T> { return std::labs(value); }
template <class T>
auto abs(T value) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, long long>::value,
                                      T> { return std::llabs(value); }
template <class T>
auto abs(T value) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<T>::value &&
                                          !std::is_floating_point<T>::value &&
                                          !std::is_same<T, int>::value &&
                                          !std::is_same<T, long>::value &&
                                          !std::is_same<T, long long>::value,
                                      T> { return std::abs(value); }


} // namespace util
```

Just replace the `std::abs` calls with `util::abs`. (Needs `c++11`.)