# Fixing odd compiler errors with std:: qualifier

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, std

I'm attempting to build source files of an open source C++ library written by someone else. This is being done on Windows with [Cygwin's mingw-w64 compiler](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/cygwin). The only compiler option I'm attaching is `-std=gnu++11` since the library depends on some C++11 features.

Here are some examples of code in their library that appears to be causing issues:

```
CPScalar & Abs()
{
    m_dValue = std::abs(m_dValue);
    return *this;
}

//...

template<typename Unit>
bool SEScalarQuantity<Unit>::Set(const SEScalarQuantity<Unit>& s)
{
  if (m_readOnly)
    throw CommonDataModelException("Scalar is marked read-only");
  if (!s.IsValid())
    return false;
  m_value = s.m_value;
  m_isnan = (std::isnan(m_value)) ? true : false;
  m_isinf = (std::isinf(m_value)) ? true : false;
  m_unit = s.m_unit;
  return true;
}
```

I get compiler errors on the `std::` qualified functions above. The compiler error on the `m_dValue = std::abs(m_dValue);` line is

> `error: call of overloaded 'abs(double&)' is ambiguous`

Which made me think it could be related to the [question of whether std::abs(0u) is ill-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750946/is-stdabs0u-ill-formed) as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30084734/4019986) to a similar SO question.

`m_isnan = (std::isnan(m_value)) ? true : false;` and the following line gives me

> `error: expected unqualified-id before '(' token`

There are countless other uses of `std::` that the compiler doesn't complain about. If I remove all of the `std::` qualifiers in the statements that are giving me errors, the code compiles beautifully.

Thing is, this [open source project](https://biogearsengine.com) is (presumably) being built by others without modification, so what am I missing here?

Comment: If there is `using namespace std;` in the global scope then either delete that and fix all the error or just drop the library and fine something else.  More reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @NathanOliver -- while removing `using namespace std;` is good advice, it won't fix this problem

Comment: One guess is that the code doesn't include `<cmath>`, which is the *formal* requirement for using the `std::` versions. With some compilers they might be visible anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `#include <cmath>` to the file being compiled. The problem is that there are a couple of overloads of `std::abs` for integer types that are declared in the header `<cstdlib>` and the compiler is complaining that it doesn't know which of those to use. What's needed, though, is `std::abs(double)`, and that's declared in `<cmath>`.

The reason that this code works with some compilers and not others is probably that there is a declaration of `std::abs(double)` coming in from some header other than `<cmath>`. That's allowed, but not required.

Comment: This works. I was hoping to avoid modifying any of the library files though, so that I don't have to worry about those modifications when upgrading to a later version