# g++ error: call of overloaded 'abs(unsigned int)' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, std

I am trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
static
unsigned iSqr( unsigned i )
{
    unsigned res1 = 2;
    unsigned res2 = i/res1;
    while( abs( res1 - res2 ) > 1 )
        {
        res1 = (res1 + res2)/2;
        res2 = i/res1;
        }
    return res1 < res2 ? res1 : res2;
}
```

using `g++ test.cc -o test`.

However, g++ compiler fails with the following error:

```
test.cc: In function 'unsigned int iSqr(unsigned int)':                                         
test.cc:8:29: error: call of overloaded 'abs(unsigned int)' is ambiguous                        
     while( abs( res1 - res2 ) > 1 )            
                             ^                  
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/cstdlib:75:0,                                          
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/stdlib.h:36,                                           
                 from test.cc:2:                
/usr/include/stdlib.h:735:12: note: candidate: int abs(int)                                     
 extern int abs (int __x) __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__)) __wur;                            
            ^~~         
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/stdlib.h:36:0,                                         
                 from test.cc:2:                
/usr/include/c++/6/cstdlib:185:3: note: candidate: __int128 std::abs(__int128)                  
   abs(__GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_0 __x) { return __x >= 0 ? __x : -__x; }                            
   ^~~                  
/usr/include/c++/6/cstdlib:180:3: note: candidate: long long int std::abs(long long int)        
   abs(long long __x) { return __builtin_llabs (__x); }                                         
   ^~~                  
/usr/include/c++/6/cstdlib:172:3: note: candidate: long int std::abs(long int)                  
   abs(long __i) { return __builtin_labs(__i); }                                                
   ^~~
```

Why this error is happening and how to fix it?

g++ version is: gcc version 6.3.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous call to abs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084577/ambiguous-call-to-abs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just cast the result to a signed datatype for abs to know which one you're calling like this:

```
while( abs( int(res1 - res2) ) > 1 )
```

but rethink again of what you need to do here as the result of minus operation on unsigned is still unsigned, so if the result goes below 0 it will turn to be a great number (as a normal overflow), so I think the use of signed variables is the best way to solve the issue in the first place

```
int iSqr( unsigned i )
{
    int res1 = 2;
    int res2 = i/res1;
    while( abs(res1 - res2) > 1 )
    {
        res1 = (res1 + res2)/2;
        res2 = i/res1;
    }
    return res1 < res2 ? res1 : res2;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `while ( abs( long(res1 - res2) ) > 1 )` would be safer, as `res1 - res2` could result in something that is higher than max signed int?

Comment: In C++ long is a 32-bit container just as int ranging from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
But you're correct for sure, it's safer to use 'long long' to avoid overflowing as it's the 64-bit container.
Also don't forget that it'll still overflow if res1 and res2 are unsigned if it goes below 0, as the result is put in a container as the operands of the operation.

Comment: Also in c++ it's recommended to use c++ style casts, ie `static_cast<long>(res1 - res2)` over the c style. I still prefer just using `int`s everywhere here though.

Comment: long is not guarantee to be 32-bit

Comment: Actually in most environments it will be 32-bit so it's safer to use long long if what we need is a "certain" 64-bit container to avoid overflowing @陳力

Comment: I believe `long` is required to be at least 32 bits? It's usually the same size as `int` though. Personally I always use [fixed width integers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) if I require a specific capacity.

Comment: The language and its implementation are different things. So, you can say `in most environments it will be 32-bit `, but you **can't** say `In C++ long is a 32-bit `

Comment: Is it implementation defined? If it's required by the standard then the implementation is non-compliant, and the size of no data types should be trusted.

Answer (score 6):

`abs` in `<stdlib.h>`(since c++11): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/

```
          int abs (          int n);
     long int abs (     long int n);
long long int abs (long long int n);
```

The call will be **ambiguous** if **overload
resolution** cannot select a match to the call that is uniquely better than such undifferentiable functions.

You can cast the argument explicitly like:

```
static_cast<int>(res1 - res2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Edit: `<cstdlib>` should handle the overloads (and should be preferred anyways), see the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084577/ambiguous-call-to-abs)

Note that there are some logic errors here. First of all, what you are doing is probably not what you want. `res1 - res2` is arithmetic between two `unsigned` types, and so the result is also going to be `unsigned`. If you go below 0, you wrap back to max int. `abs()` is pointless here, that value will *never be negative* because the type disallows it. Even with the header that compiles this code, the compiler will still warn about this.

I highly recommend you stick to signed integers when dealing with arithmetic to avoid these pitfalls, and if you *really* need the storage, use 64-bit integers.

So my real answer would be, switch `unsigned` to `int`

Also note: `unsigned res2 = i / res1;` res2 will be truncated towards 0 here, I'm not sure if that is what you want or not.

Comment: Could you please specify how exactly I should amend the code, to make it use signed integers?